# move content in a column past an empty column using the excel formula

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula

how to move content in a column past an empty column using the excel formula. for example a1 = banana, a2 = "", a3 = apple, a4 = tomato, a5 = "", a6 = grape. and the results from top to bottom like this, banana, apple, tomato, grape, thank you.

Comment: Are u asking about concatenate the cells or A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 ?? If not give some more explanations with example. Else please update your question properly to solve your problem.

Comment: what I asked above is to overlay the column filled in the top through the empty column below. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use a formula:

[image]

In cell `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT($A$1:$A$6)*ROW($A$1:$A$6),ROW()+COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$6))),"")
```

Drag down...

**EDIT1:** To make clear it works when the range would start in row 15, you just need to edit the range from `$A$1:$A$6` to `$A$1:$A$20`:

[image]

**EDIT2:** To make clear you have to change more references when you start moving around the functions and data:

The formula in `C6` would become:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$11,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT($B$6:$B$11)*ROW($B$6:$B$11),ROW(A1)+COUNTBLANK($B$6:$B$11))),"")
```

[image]

If you really want to understand what is going on, also try and evaluate the formula through the build-in function on the `Formulas` tab.

Comment: great, but why does this formula not work if it starts from a column, for example c15?

Comment: @Borneo, do you meant `Row` instead of `Column` perhaps?

Comment: yes. for example the data in c15, and the formula in d15.

Comment: @borneo, see my edited answer, you can paste the formula in any cell other than column A to make it work.

Comment: ok. when the main data is taken from line C15 = red, C16 = blue, C17 = "", C18 = pink, C19 = "", C20 = black ... and the formula is in D15 = =IFERROR(INDEX($C$15:$C$20,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT$C$15:$C$20)*ROW($C$15:$C$20),ROW()+COUNTBLANK($C$15:$C$20))),"").... this formula doesn't work, why?

Comment: @borneo, cause you haven't changed the referenced ranges. Please see the edited answer for an example.

Comment: I start from C13, with this formula, but not function `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$26,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT($C$13:$C$26)*ROW($C$13:$C$26),ROW(C13)+COUNTBLANK($C$13:$C$26))),"")`

Comment: @borneo, so from `C13` it's just a small adjustment: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$26,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT($C$13:$C$26)*ROW($C$13:$C$26),ROW(A1)+COUNTBLANK($C$13:$C$26))),"")`. Do you see how the range at the start, actually starts form `C1`?

Comment: thank you for the effect formula. but it's still a question in my mind, the index function that I didn't expect before bouncing up, and also for row (a1) which actually works for what?

Comment: The first `INDEX` range is where you want to pull data from. In the second part of the formula with `AGGREGATE` we multiply a `TRUE` (derived from `ISTEXT`) with the `ROW` of these values. So the array would be like `13,16,17 etc.`. Now that's why you need index to start from row 1! And we use `ROW(A1)` to just get the number `1`, nothing else :), Because when you drag down, that will evaluate to 1, 2 ,3 ,4 etc. Again, you should really try the in-build evaluate to try and understand the formula better.

Comment: detailed and useful explanation. I found the problem, why before the formula was problematic. it turns out that the data that appears empty contains a formula, so that in its application the data is not shown in full. it functions when I delete a formula and switch to filling data manually. thanks again for the solution. ;)