# Problem with aggregate and row function to jump zero value

Tags: excel, ms-office, formula

I have the data in column A1 and the formula in column B1 with the following writing.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$14,AGGREGATE(15,3,ISTEXT($A$1:$A$14)*ROW($A$1:$A$14),ROW()+COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$14))),"")
```

like a picture.

[image]
maybe in this forum can explain why I can't implement aggregate and row functions if I move data to column C13 and the formula in column D13. sorry, it's still new in excel.

Comment: The problem is that when you copy paste or move around functions, you will see that the references start changing. As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263517/move-content-in-a-column-past-an-empty-column-using-the-excel-formula). So for example the `ROW()` bit in the formula ensures that `AGGREGATE(15` will get the smallest number from first row. If you move around this formula, you need to reference `ROW(A1)` in that formula and adjust the other ranges. I edited my answer over there to make it even clearer (hopefully)

Comment: in the previous question I stopped using row. I am confused about this

Comment: Is it row after * or after ,? `*ROW($A$1:$A$14) ,ROW()`

Comment: I have updated the answer in your previous question to make that clear :). Please have a look there.